# Event Args not being passed to RelayCommand as parameter when using EventArgsConverter property inside EventToCommandBehavior

Tags: mvvm, .net-maui

I am building an app that scans QR codes and I need to pass in the results from the QR code scanned to a relay command in the view model.
I am using Zxing library to handle the QR scanning, and they have an event that returns those results. Since I am using MVVM architecture, I want to pass those results to the view model.

So I created my own converter and pass that to the EventArgsConverter but for some reason the converter is not being called, and the parameters in the relay command is set to null. any idea on why this might be happening?

Yes, I have added the converter as a static resource.

Control:

```
<controls:CameraBarcodeReaderView Grid.Row="0" IsDetecting="True" IsTorchOn="False" Options="{Binding BarcodeReaderOptions}">
        <controls:CameraBarcodeReaderView.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="BarcodesDetected" Command="{Binding BarcodesDectectedCommand}" CommandParameter="Test" EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource BarcodeDetectionEventArgsConverter}" />
        </controls:CameraBarcodeReaderView.Behaviors>
    </controls:CameraBarcodeReaderView>
```

Converter:

```
public class BarcodeDetectionEventArgsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value is not BarcodeDetectionEventArgs barcodeDetectionEventArgs)
            throw new ArgumentException("Expected value to be of type BarcodeDetectionEventArgs", nameof(value));
        return barcodeDetectionEventArgs.Results;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

command in view model:

```
        public ICommand BarcodesDectectedCommand => new RelayCommand<object>(OnBarcodesDetectedCommand);
    private void OnBarcodesDetectedCommand(object obj)
    {
        var results = obj as BarcodeResult[];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known open issue about this problem.

You can follow it up here: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/569 .

Thanks for you support and feedback.

Comment: Thanks! this really help aswer my question and solve my problem